# Linux join muliple files with muliple columns

Tags: linux, join, awk, sed, merge

I have one issues that have to merge serveral different files.

Just for example two files *But Column is Same just different values.
Each files has tab delimiter in side.
Join all columns by ID information.

First file Test.txt

```
    ID     ID2     ID3    Name  Telephone       
    1       A       +     John    011
    1       B       -     Mike    012
    2       C       +     Sam    013
    3       A       -     Jena    014
    4       B       +     Peter    015
```

Second file Test2.txt

```
    ID     ID2     ID3    Name  Telephone       
    2       C       +     Henry    013
    3       A       -     Ho    014
    1       A       +     Jamy    011
    1       B       -     Mark    012
    4       B       +     Jung    015
```

Then Final result

```
    ID     ID2     ID3    Name  Telephone    Name  Telephone
    1       A       +     John    011        Jamy    011
    1       B       -     Mike    012        Mark    012
    2       C       +     Sam     013        Henry   013
    3       A       -     Jena    014        Ho      014
    4       B       +     Peter   015        Jung    015
```

So combine depends on ID 1 ID2 ID3,

I tried to use join like 
join -a1 -a2 -a3 Test1.txt Test2.txt > Test3.txt

Something like this but there is problem with Performance and multiple file join
And I am not sure that is correctly join.

Does anyone have best Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="\t" '
    {key = $1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $3}
    FNR==NR {line[key]=$0; next} 
    key in line {print line[$1,$2,$3], $4, $5}
' Test.txt Test2.txt
```

```
ID  ID2 ID3 Name    Telephone   Name    Telephone
2   C   +   Sam 013 Henry   013
3   A   -   Jena    014 Ho  014
1   A   +   John    011 Jamy    011
1   B   -   Mike    012 Mark    012
4   B   +   Peter   015 Jung    015
```

If you want the output sorted, pipe the output into `| { read header; echo "$header"; sort; }`

With `join`, you can only join on one field. You'd have to resort to something like

```
join -j1 -t$'\t' <(sed 's/\t/:/;s/\t/:/' Test.txt|sort) \
                 <(sed 's/\t/:/;s/\t/:/' Test2.txt|sort) | 
sed 's/:/\t/;s/:/\t/'
```

and then, that leaves the header at the bottom (which you can fix with `| tac | { read header; echo "$header"; tac; }`)

---

Response to comment:

```
awk -F"\t" '
    {key = $1 FS $2 FS $3}
    NR == 1 {header = key}
    !(key in result) {result[key] = $0; next}
    { for (i=4; i <= NF; i++) result[key] = result[key] FS $i }
    END {
        print result[header]
        delete result[header]
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"    # if using GNU awk
        for (key in result) print result[key]
    }
' Test.txt Test2.txt  # ... and other files
```

Comment: Awsome almost close but As I mention it could be multiple files, Is it possible print all columns some flexible command instead of $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 ? thanks!!

Comment: key is same $1,$2,$3 but the other column can be multiple

Comment: answer updated. You should update your question so the requirements are more obvious (for example, add a column to Test2).

Comment: Hi I add more question for intersection. If you are interested please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652252/linux-combine-two-files-by-column.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU bash, GNU core utilities and GNU awk:

```
join -j 5 <(sort -n Test.txt) <(sort -n Test2.txt) | awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5,$1,$9,$1}' | column -t
```

Output:

```
ID  ID2  ID3  Name   Telephone  Name   Telephone
1   A    +    John   011        Jamy   011
1   B    -    Mike   012        Mark   012
2   C    +    Sam    013        Henry  013
3   A    -    Jena   014        Ho     014
4   B    +    Peter  015        Jung   015
```

Comment: `join` wants lexically sorted files.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` you can just build your strings for the unique keys seen in your file. You can then pipe the output to `column -t` for pretty printing.

I have used column 1, 2 and 3 as keys and building remaining columns from every file to the original line.

```
awk --re-interval -F"\t" '
{ key = $1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $3 }
{
    if (line[key]) {
        sub (/([^\t]+\t+){3}/,"");
        line[key] = line[key] FS $0
    }
    else {
        line[key] = $0
    }
}
END {
     for (key in line) print line[key]
}' file* | column -t | sort -r
ID  ID2  ID3  Name   Telephone  Name   Telephone
4   B    +    Peter  015        Jung   015
3   A    -    Jena   014        Ho     014
2   C    +    Sam    013        Henry  013
1   B    -    Mike   012        Mark   012
1   A    +    John   011        Jamy   011
```

**Note:** If you are using GNU `awk v4` or later or BSD `awk`, then you need not specify `--re-interval`.

---

If you are open to `perl` then you can do it in single shot:

```
perl -F"\t" -lane '
    $" = "\t";
    $key = "@F[0..2]";
    push @{ $line{$key} }, @F[3..$#F];
}{
    print join "\t", $_, @{ $line{$_} } for grep { $_ =~ /ID/ } sort keys %line;
    print join "\t", $_, @{ $line{$_} } for grep { not $_ =~ /ID/ } sort keys %line
' file*
```

Comment: When I tested this solution using three input files, I see different output than what you have shown.  In my output I see ID columns included once for each input file.

Comment: @carl.anderson What OS are you working on? I tested with 3 files basically providing same files over and over and it works fine. I think the issue might be with the header line that would be printed out of order.

Comment: OSX.  In Ubuntu (Precise) my awk doesn't even have the --re-interval flag.  Regardless, it shouldn't matter.Are you using _tab_ delimited files, as the OP specified?  If not, that could cause the `sub` command to do nothing, include more than you intended.

Comment: @carl.anderson Updated. For BSD `awk` you don't need `--re-interval`. I added that to the answer.