# Linux Combine two files by column

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to combine two files as below (Intersection)

```
ID     Name  Telephone       
1      John     011
2      Sam      013
3      Jena     014
4      Peter    015
```

Second file Test2.txt

```
1       Test1    Test2
2       Test3    Test4
3       Test5    Test6
4       Test7    Test8
5       Test7    Test8
6       Test7    Test8
7       Test7    Test8
8       Test7    Test8
9       Test7    Test8
```

Then Final result

```
ID     Name  Telephone    Remark1  Remark2
1      John    011        Test1    Test2
2      Sam     013        Test3    Test4
3      Jena    014        Test5    Test6
4      Peter   015        Test7    Test8
```

I did like this as below,

```
awk -F"\t" '
    {key = $1 }
    NR == 1 {header = key}
    !(key in result) {result[key] = $0; next}
    { for (i=2; i <= NF; i++) result[key] = result[key] FS $i }
    END {
        print result[header]
        delete result[header]
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"    
        for (key in result) print result[key]
    }
' Test1.txt Test2.txt > result.txt
```

And I just notice that this is Union set.
Including all data Test1 and Test2.

I would like to show only for Intersection case as what I expected result.
(1, 2 ,3 ,4) only

Do you guys have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '
NR==1   { print $0, "Remark1", "Remark2"; next }
NR==FNR { a[$1]=$0; next }
$1 in a { print a[$1], $2, $3 }
' Test1.txt Test2.txt
ID     Name  Telephone  Remark1 Remark2
1      John     011     Test1   Test2
2      Sam      013     Test3   Test4
3      Jena     014     Test5   Test6
4      Peter    015     Test7   Test8
```

Answer (score 27):

It is far easier to use the  [`join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) command:

```
$ cat a.txt 
ID     Name  Telephone       
1      John     011
2      Sam      013
3      Jena     014
4      Peter    015
$ cat b.txt 
ID     Remark1  Remark2       
1       Test1    Test2
2       Test3    Test4
3       Test5    Test6
4       Test7    Test8
5       Test7    Test8
6       Test7    Test8
7       Test7    Test8
8       Test7    Test8
9       Test7    Test8
$ join a.txt b.txt 
ID Name Telephone Remark1 Remark2
1 John 011 Test1 Test2
2 Sam 013 Test3 Test4
3 Jena 014 Test5 Test6
4 Peter 015 Test7 Test8
```

Use the [`column`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html) command to pretty print it:

```
$ join a.txt b.txt | column -t
ID  Name   Telephone  Remark1  Remark2
1   John   011        Test1    Test2
2   Sam    013        Test3    Test4
3   Jena   014        Test5    Test6
4   Peter  015        Test7    Test8
```

Comment: `join` is the right tool, but beware that the sort order used by `sort` and by `join` are not exactly the same. Best to use `env LANG=en_EN sort ...` and `env LANG=en_UN join ...`. A frustrating problem. For more, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12942/join-file-2-not-in-sorted-order

Comment: when I try to do with my case correctly joined but tab delimited is disappeared. And if I use column -t looks like broken format.

Comment: @glennjackman I already did and no resuly file size 0 so I tried join -a1 -t $'\t' test1.txt test2.txt > result.txt then no combine. result will be same as test1.txt and result.txt.

Comment: The answer assumes the 2nd file has a header line. does it?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid thanks for the feedback I never had the issue but it is good to know. The data in this case was sorted already though, and I skipped the `sort` part.

Comment: @glennjackman oh 2nd file does not have header line do they need? then I will insert header first for second file

Comment: @glennjackman you are right, I am now confused as I copy/pasted the examples on my system and in my files the second file has a header and I am sure I did not insert it myself. But the question indeed does not present a header in the second file.

Comment: @damienfrancois Thank you for your answer and sorry I edited question and during that time u already copy and paste I am sorry for that ! I will try to make header and try again

Comment: Still it's not join only header part is join but main part is not join problem is if I using just join then correctly join but It need to be tab delimited and if I use -t $'\t' it looks like does not correct

Comment: And also if I use | column -t then show error message "column: line too long"

Comment: @glennjackman: the header problem can be solved like this: `join ./phones.txt <(echo -e "ID Remark1 Remark2\n\`cat ./remarks.txt\`") | column -t`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, better would be `<(echo -e "ID\tRemark1\tRemark2"; cat ./remarks.txt)`

Comment: @clear.choi, try `sed '1{s/$/\tRemark1\tRemark2/;q}' file1; join -t$'\t' <(sed 1d file1|sort) <(sort file2)`

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative would be [`pr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pr.1.html) which is used for formating files to print.

```
$ pr -tm -w 50 Test1.txt Test2.txt
ID     Name  Telephone   ID Remark1  Remark2
1      John      011     1   Test1    Test2
2      Sam       013     2   Test3    Test4
3      Jena      014     3   Test5    Test6
4      Peter     015     4   Test7    Test8
                         5   Test7    Test8
                         6   Test7    Test8
                         7   Test7    Test8
                         8   Test7    Test8
                         9   Test7    Test8
```

The most important is the `m` flag which merges files into columns. The `t` flag removes headers and footers - since we're not going to print on paper, we don't need them. The last `w` flag is for setting width.

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk -F"\t" '
     {key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4}
     NR == 1 {header = key}
     !(key in result) {result[key] = $0; next}
     { for (i=5; i <= NF; i++) result[key] = result[key] FS $i }
     END {
         print result[header]
         delete result[header]
         PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"    # if using GNU awk
         for (key in result) print result[key]
     }
 ' Test1.txt Test2.txt ... > result.txt
```