# Match col values from two different datasets (dbSNP ID's) and merge dataset

Tags: r, shell, bioinformatics

I have two datasets A and B. I wish to match dbSNP ID's from dataset A with B. If matched, then for that SNPid's want to fetch the other col values for that row and merge with cols present in dataset A.

[image]

**Note:** New in Bioinformatics, exploring in Linux scripts or R.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer to this site to ask proper question: [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sure. I am new to here. Please allow this question to be answered. I will take care of the post standards

Comment: Using R, possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871)

Comment: Using shell/awk/join, possible duplicate of [Linux Combine two files by column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25652252/680068)

Answer (score 1):

Use [merge](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/merge)

```
merge(A, B, by = 'dbSNP_ID')
```

This finds entries in the column specified by 'by' that are common to both datasets and combines row information. The output is a dataset with only entries common to both datasets and with all other col values for matching rows.