# Selecting specific rows of a tab-delimited file using bash (linux)

Tags: r, linux, bash

I have a directory lot of txt tab-delimited files with several rows and columns, e.g.

```
File1
Id    Sample   Time ...  Variant[Column16] ...
1     s1       t0        c.B481A:p.G861S
2     s2       t2        c.C221C:p.D461W
3     s5       t1        c.G31T:p.G61R
```

```
File2
Id    Sample   Time ...  Variant[Column16] ...
1     s1       t0        c.B481A:p.G861S
2     s2       t2        c.C21C:p.D61W
3     s5       t1        c.G1T:p.G1R
```

and what I am looking for is to create a new file with:

- all the different variants uniq
- the number of variants repeteated
- and the file location

i.e.:

```
NewFile
Variant             Nº of repeated       Location
c.B481A:p.G861S     2                    File1,File2
c.C221C:p.D461W     1                    File1
c.G31T:p.G61R       1                    File1
c.C21C:p.D61W       1                    File2
c.G1T:p.G1R         1                    File2
```

I think using a basic script in bash with awk sort and uniq it will work, but I do not know where to start. Or if using Rstudio or python(3) is easier, I could try.

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not sure about column 3 (as an easy one liner, though you could find out a way to do it I'm sure) Something like this might work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652252/linux-combine-two-files-by-column

For 1 and 2 you can use: `awk '{print $4 }' file1.txt > combined.txt` and `awk '{print $4 }' file2.txt >> combined.txt` then `sort combined.txt | uniq -c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure bash would be hard I think but everyone has some awk lying around :D

```
awk 'FNR==1{next}
{
  ++n[$16];
  if ($16 in a) {
    a[$16]=a[$16]","ARGV[ARGIND]
  }else{
    a[$16]=ARGV[ARGIND]
  }
}
END{
printf("%-24s %6s    %s\n","Variant","Nº","Location");
for (v in n) printf("%-24s %6d    %s\n",v,n[v],a[v])}' *
```

Comment: Thats was what I'm looking for, but I am not sure why it prints me also a line with a number and not with the variant

Comment: @WindSur if the files are exactly as you said they are this should not happen and I tested it. It might be though that there are empty lines or lines with a missing variant or lines of a different format altogether. If the lines are actually only separated by tabs and never by spaces you should use `awk -FS='\t'`. To see if there are empty lines use `awk '/^${print ARGV[ARGIND], FNR}' *`, better yet you should upload two files so we can reproduce the behavior.

Comment: I've tried, but I didn't see anything
here some files:
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/p5jdkvs3vmdv14b/AADT9ZjnJcU0tRqyjhLQtLAQa?dl=0)
In that case, the variant column is the 10th position or 9th if we start from 0

Comment: If your files contain the variant in column 10 you will need to replace $16 with $10 .
`awk 'FNR==1{next}{++n[$10];if ($10 in a) {a[$10]=a[$10]","ARGV[ARGIND]}else{a[$10]=ARGV[ARGIND]}}END{printf("%-24s %6s    %s\n","Variant","Nº","Location");for (v in n) printf("%-24s %6d    %s\n",v,n[v],a[v])}' *`

Comment: yes, of course I did it, but it is not working with these files. all the files are tab-delimited, so I wrote
`awk '-FS='\t'{++n[$10];if ($10 in a) {a[$10]=a[$10]","ARGV[ARGIND]}else{a[$10]=ARGV[ARGIND]}}END{printf("%-24s %6s %s\n","Variant","Nº","Location");for (v in n) printf("%-24s %6d %s\n",v,n[v],a[v])}' *` ? but doesnt work

Comment: @WindSur `awk -F'\t' 'FNR==1{next}{++n[$10];if ($10 in a) {a[$10]=a[$10]","ARGV[ARGIND]}else{a[$10]=ARGV[ARGIND]}}END{printf("%-24s %6s %s\n","Variant","Nº","Location");for (v in n) printf("%-24s %6d %s\n",v,n[v],a[v])}' *`

Answer (score 2):

Pure bash. Requires version 4.0+

```sh
# two associative arrays
declare -A files
declare -A count

# use a glob pattern that matches your files
for f in File{1,2}; do
    {
        read header
        while read -ra fields; do
            variant=${fields[3]}        # use index "15" for 16th column
            (( count[$variant] += 1 ))
            files[$variant]+=",$f"
        done
    } < "$f"
done

for variant in "${!count[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\t%d\t%s\n" "$variant" "${count[$variant]}" "${files[$variant]#,}"
done
```

outputs

```
c.B481A:p.G861S 2   File1,File2
c.G1T:p.G1R 1   File2
c.C221C:p.D461W 1   File1
c.G31T:p.G61R   1   File1
c.C21C:p.D61W   1   File2
```

The order of the output lines is indeterminate: associative arrays have no particular ordering.

Comment: Great! but I am not familiar with the first lines, `declare -A`, should I write the path there?
And if I have more than 2 files?

Comment: @WindSur You grab your files using the pattern `File{1,2}` in line 6, so in your case this might simply be `*` or `*.txt` .